# TypeError: Member "encodeCall" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in abi

Tags: solidity, abi, bytes

I am trying to test `abi.encodeCall` on Remix. I have this function

function getTestData() external pure returns (bytes memory){
// passing empty args ()
return abi.encodeCall(TargetContract.send,());
}

this is the version

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (actually lack of feature) that has been fixed since Solidity 0.8.12: [Release note: "General: Support ContractName.functionName for abi.encodeCall, in addition to external function pointers."](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.8.12). The fix is to change your version pragma like below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
contract TargetContract{
    function send() external {}
}
contract Test{
    function getTestData() external pure returns (bytes memory){
        return abi.encodeCall(TargetContract.send,()); 
        // another solution: return abi.encodeWithSelector(TargetContract.send.selector, (""));
    }
}
```

You can also use the alternative in the comment (using `abi.encodeWithSelector`), it can also work for solc version before 0.8.12.